# How do I change Textbox Header color on hover?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3

I have the following:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" Header="Name" >
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
</TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
```

Is there a way through the DataTemplate or Xaml behaviors to change the Foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XamlBehaviors`.

Add Nuget `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` and references in Xaml.

```
 xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
 xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
```

Handle `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` event on `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" Header="Name" >
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" />
                            </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                            </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
</TextBox>
```